# SSH on console google cloud permission denied (publickey) with google-cloud-sdk file error

Tags: linux, ssh, google-cloud-platform, putty

I'm new on cloud computing and I'm trying to use SSH to control my VM instance but when I use command (with debug)

> gcloud compute ssh my-instance-name --verbosity=debug

it's show error

> DEBUG: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code
>   [255]. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line
>   983, in Execute
>       resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)   File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py",
>   line 784, in Run
>       resources = command_instance.Run(args)   File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/compute/ssh.py", line 262, in
>   Run
>       return_code = cmd.Run(ssh_helper.env, force_connect=True)   File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/util/ssh/ssh.py",
>   line 1256, in Run
>       raise CommandError(args[0], return_code=status) CommandError: [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]. ERROR:
>   (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

I try to solve the problem in this link but it's not work
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/O-c10TM4ZLM

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1):

SSH error code 255 is a general error returned by GCP. You can try one of the following options.

**1. Wait a few minutes and try again. It is possible that:**

- The instance has not finished starting up.
- Metadata for SSH keys has not finished being propagated to the project or instance.

  - The Guest Environment has not yet read the SSH keys metadata.

**2. Verify that SSH access to the instance is not blocked by a firewall**.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list | grep "tcp:22"
```

If necessary, create a firewall rule to allow TCP 22 for a given VPC network, subnet, or instance tag.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create ssh-allow-incoming --priority=0 --allow=tcp:22 --network=[VPC-Network]
```

**3. Make sure that the root volume is not out of disk space. Messages like the following will be visible in the [console log](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output) when it is out of disk space:**

> ...No space left on device...
>
> ...google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler.
>   [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp',
>   '/usr/tmp', '/']...

**4. Make sure that the instance has not run out of memory**

**5. Verify that temporary SSH Keys metadata is set for either the [project](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide) or [instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only).**

Finally you could follow any of their [supported](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools) or [third-party](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools) methods

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the correct IAM permissions, it is much easier and preferred by GCP to use OSlogin to ssh into an instance, rather than manage ssh keys

in cloud shell, enter this

```
gcloud compute --project PROJECTID project-info add-metadata --metadata enable-oslogin=TRUE
```

This enables OSLogin on all instances in a project, instead of using ssh keys gcp will check your IAM permissions and authenticate based on those.

If you are not project owner, make sure you have the compute.osloginviewer or admin permissions in Cloud IAM

Once enables, try SSHing into the instance again using the command you posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a concrete answer but I think at first you should set your project by :

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

Then

```
gcloud compute ssh my-instance-name --verbosity=debug
```

This link would be useful:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh